# Python, TypeError: rect argument inavlid

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror

I am very new to Python and am trying to make a snake game, But I am being told multiple times that the 'rect argument is invalid'
It is :

> ```
> File "c:\Users\Idontwanttomention\Desktop\Coding\Pygame\Snake.py", line 47, in <module>
>    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),(snake_pos[0], snake_pos[1],15, 15))
> TypeError: rect argument is invalid
> ```

This is my code :

```py
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (800,600) )

#snake_pos = [300,200]
snake_pos = [ [400,300] , [420,300] , [440,300] ]
apple_pos = [ random.randint(100,700), random.randint(100,500) ]

step = 10
up = (0, -step)
down = (0, step)
left = (-step, 0)
right = (step, 0)

direction = left

# TITLE

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill ((230,195,255))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP: 
                direction = up
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN: 
                direction = down 
                #snake_pos[1] += 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT: 
                direction = left
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: 
                direction = right
                #snake_pos[0] += 10



    # MOVING SNAKE
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),(apple_pos[0], apple_pos[1],15, 15))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),(snake_pos[0], snake_pos[1],15, 15))
    
    
    clock.tick(5)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`snake_pos` is a list of tuples. Each tuple in the list is a part of the snakes body. Therefore, you must draw one rectangle for each part of the body. Use a `for`-loop to draw the snake:

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    # APPLE
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),(apple_pos[0], apple_pos[1], 15, 15))
    # MOVING SNAKE
    for pos in snake_pos:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),(pos[0], pos[1], 15, 15))
```